# How to get Country for Google Places API nearby search

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using Google Places API to get nearby places, but I've noticed that while I get the place names and addresses, the results don't include the Country.

Is there a way to get the country included in the results?

This is the call I'm using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=<lat,lng>&radius=100&sensor=true&key=<api_key>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Geocoding API is what you want.

Try

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Calgary,%20Alberta&sensor=false
```

it'll return fully formatted address info in several ways (split by administrative level, formatted as an address,etc.)

also the place Types blog in google api will help..link is [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)

Comment: Thanks codebreaker. I was hoping to avoid an extra call, but I only need it once the user has selected a Google Place, so that's not too bad. It's nice to have your confirmation, knowing I'm not overlooking something easy and obvious!